# Finding the asymptote of an irrational function

Tags: calculus

Got stuck a little with when I was doing Demidovich's Analysis. Here is the problem:

> Problem 1487: Find the graph of 
>   $
> \sqrt[3]{(x^3-x^2-x+1)}
> $

I solved it through inequalities of means:

$
\sqrt[3]{(x^3-x^2-x+1)}= \sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2(x+1)}\lt\frac{3x-1}3
$

But I wonder if there are other ways around it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: an irrational function*

Comment: Usually you search the limit of $f(x)/x$ to get the slope, then $f(x)-mx$ for the intercept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$f(x)
=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)^{1/3}
$
and
$g(x)
=x+a/3$.

$g(x)^3
=x^3+ax^2+a^2x/3+a^3/27
$.

Since
$u^{1/3}-v^{1/3}
=\dfrac{u-v}{u^{2/3}+(uv)^{1/3}+v^{2/3}}
$,
then,
as $x \to \infty$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)-g(x)
&=(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)^{1/3}-(x+a/3)\\
&=\dfrac{x^3+ax^2+bx+c-(x^3+ax^2+a^2x/3+a^3/27)}{(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)^{2/3}+(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)^{1/3}(x+a/3)+(x+a/3)^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{(b-a^2/3)x+c-a^3/27}{x^2\left((1+a/x+b/x^2+c/x^3)^{2/3}+(1+a/x+b/x^2+c/x^3)^{1/3}(1+a/(3x))+(1+a/(3x))^{2}\right)}\\
&=\dfrac{(b-a^2/3)x+c-a^3/27}{x^2(1+O(1/x))}\\
&=O(1/x)\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2-x+1}$.  Suppose we have an oblique asymptote in the form $y=mx+b$.

To find $m$, we have $$m=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1.$$

To find $b$, we have $$b=\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)-mx=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{x^3-x^2-x+1}-x=-\frac13.$$

Therefore, we have an oblique asymptote $\boxed{y=x-\frac13}$.